# Drawer navigator minSwipeDistance property

Tags: react-native

I want to open drawer with touching anywhere on screen.I tried with `minSwipeDistance` property of drawer navigator.Although I didn't get error It didn't work.How should I implement this process into my code? If anyone knows help me please! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For React Navigation V5

put this to take the device width

```
function ProfileDrawer() {
   const dimensions = useWindowDimensions();
```

and **edgeWidth** is what you want I think

```
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Profile"
                          edgeWidth={dimensions.width}
                              >
```

You can check the Official Page to see detail for DrawerNavigator:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#props